# Discrete quotient group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I have a hard time understanding quotient groups. For example, I need to make sense of the expression $$\mathcal{S}_3 (1,3,5) / \mathcal{Z}_2 (3,5).$$ Here, $\mathcal{S}_3 (1,3,5)$ is a symmetric group of permutations, $$\mathcal{S}_3 (1,3,5) = \{(1,3,5),(3,1,5),(3,5,1),(1,5,3),(5,1,3),(5,3,1)\}.$$

What is $\mathcal{Z}_2 (3,5)$ (a cyclic group?) and how to interpret the above quotient?

Comment: Unfortunately this one doesn't make a lot of sense because you need a *normal subgroup* to take the quotient and not an arbitrary subgroup. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I want. I'm reading a paper in which they use this exact group.

Comment: Probably the subgroup generated by the transposition $(35)$, which is of order $2$. The quotient then would denote the `cosets` modulo this subgroup.

Comment: @Bernard Could you please dumb it down for me? I'm a physicist. What are the elements of this group?

Comment: In this case, your group $\;\mathcal S_3\;$ is isomorphic with the symmetric group $\;S_3\;$ on three letters or objects (usually, on $\;\{1,2,3\}\;$), and  this group has only one single -trivial **normal** subgroup, which is $\;A_3=$ the alternating group, of order three. Unless that odd-looking (for a mathematician) thing $\;\mathcal Z_2\;$ is this alternatig group, you can **not** form the quotient group of your question.

Comment: @Timbuc Can I interpret it as the group of all permutations of (1,3,5) in which I treat 3 and 5 as identical?

Comment: @LittleBrownOne If you have, or want, to treat $\;3,5\;$ as the same object then you don't have the symmetric group $\;S_3\;$ but rather $\;S_2\;$, with only two elements. I don't think this is what you meant.

Comment: @LittleBrownOne If you could share a reference to the article, I'm sure someone would have a look and give a second opinion on what it says.

Comment: @Timbuc I was thinking of interpreting the quotient group as $\{(1,3,5),(3,1,5),(3,5,1)\}$.

Comment: @Myself [link](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0703311) See discussion after Eq. (2)

Comment: @LittleBrownOne I could never get used to the weird way physicists have of denoting things (and of doing what they call, pretty metaphorically, "mathematics"), yet in this case I still am lost: in order to be able to form a quotient group we **must** have a normal subgroup, and the only non-trivial one in $\;S_3\;$ is of order three, rendering a quotient group of order two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z_2(3,5)$ probably denotes the cyclic subgroup of order $2$ generated by the transposition (35), i.e. $\{e,(3\,5)\}$. $S_3(1,3,5)/Z_2(3,5)$ would the denote the (left) cosets of $Z_2$ in $S_3$. As $Z_2(3,5)$ is *not* a `normal` subgroup, left cosets are different from right cosets, and the quotient cannot be given a group structure inherited from that of $S_3(1,3,5)$.

There are $3$ cosets, which are pairs of permutations that can be deduced from each other by right multiplication by elements of $Z_2$:

1. $(1\,3\,5)$ & $(1\,5\,3)$
2. $(3\,1\,5)$ & $(3\,5\,1)$
3. $(5\,1\,3)$ & $(5\,3\,1)$

Note it is much easier to compute if you use the representation of permutation as a product of disjoint cycles. For instance the $(3\,5)$ transposition (which means $3\to5\to3\,$, $1$ unchanged) is what you denote the $(1\,5\,3)$ permutation.

Comment: From a practical point of view, I start with $(135)$ and transpose the last two elements to get $(153)$. This is my first coset. Now I take another permutation, which is not contained in the above coset, e.g. $(351)$ and permute its last two elements to get $(315)$ and this makes the second coset. The last two permutations are then my third coset. Is this right?

Comment: Yes  but you're constantly juggling between two representations and this makes it uneasy to check the results.